# ¿Por qué al intentar recorrer un array para imprimirlo con jsPDF se sobrescribe y solo muestra ultimo registro?

Tags: javascript, array, jspdf

```
function(resp){
    var valores = eval(resp);
    //alert(valores);

    var pdf = new jsPDF();

    for(i=0;i<valores.length;i++){
        datos=(i+':'+valores[i][0]+"*"+valores[i][1]+"*"+valores[i][2]+"*"+valores[i][3]+"*"+valores[i][4]+"*"+valores[i][5]+"*"+valores[i][6]+"*"+valores[i][7]+"*"+valores[i][8]+"*"+valores[i][9]+"*"+valores[i][10]+"*"+valores[i][11]+"*"+valores[i][12]+"*"+valores[i][13]+"*"+valores[i][14]+"*"+valores[i][15]+"*"+valores[i][16]);

        var d=datos.split("*"); 

        }

    pdf.text(30, 20, d);

    pdf.save('reporte.pdf');
```

Comment: En var d=datos.split("*");  lo estas sobreescribiendo. la variable **d** solo tomara el ultimo valor.

Comment: Si, ¿sabrias como hacer para que me muestre todos los registros? alguna idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var pdf = new jsPDF();
 var d = "";

 for(i=0;i<valores.length;i++){
    datos = (i+':'+valores[i][0]+"*"+valores[i][1]+"*"+valores[i][2]+"*"+valores[i][3]+"*"+valores[i][4]+"*"+valores[i][5]+"*"+valores[i][6]+"*"+valores[i][7]+"*"+valores[i][8]+"*"+valores[i][9]+"*"+valores[i][10]+"*"+valores[i][11]+"*"+valores[i][12]+"*"+valores[i][13]+"*"+valores[i][14]+"*"+valores[i][15]+"*"+valores[i][16]);
    d = d + " \n " + datos.split("*"); 
 } 

 pdf.text(30, 20, d);
 pdf.save('reporte.pdf');
```